# Por qué cuando hago esta tabla en Latex me aparece el cartel: Undefined Control sequence?

Tags: latex

tengo una duda de Látex. cuando hago esta tabla:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\cline{1-2}
 $N$ & $\tau$ &  $\alpha$_E $\pm$  $\Delta$$\alpha$_E  & $\alpha$_P $\pm$  
 $\Delta$$\alpha$_P  & $\alpha$_D $\pm$  $\Delta$$\alpha$_D  & {R}^{2}_E /  {R}^{2}_P 
 / {R}^{2}_D\\ 
\hline \hline


\multirow{24} 
& 0,25 &  0,99$\pm$  0,07 & 0,91 $\pm$  0,03 &  2,72 $\pm$    0,02 & 0,67/ 0,54 /0,91 
\\ \cline{2-2}  \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  

& 1  & 0,97 $\pm$  0,07 & 0,92 $\pm$  0,03 &  2,71 $\pm$    0,02  & 0,76 / 0,54 / 
0,95 \\ \cline{2-2}  \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  

& 4  & 0,96 $\pm$  0,07 & 0,91$\pm$  0,03 & 2,71 $\pm$    0,02  & 0,88 / 0,82 / 0,89 
\\  \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline


\hline

\multirow{32} 
& 0,25 &  0,96 $\pm$  0,06 & 0,92$\pm$  0,03 & 2,71  $\pm$    0,02 &  0,88/ 0,82 / 
0,88 \\ \cline{2-2}  \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  

& 1 & 0,95 $\pm$  0,07 & 0,94$\pm$  0,03 &  2,27 $\pm$    0,02  & 0,85 / 0,95 / 0,89 
\\   \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  


& 4  & 0,95 $\pm$  0,06 & 0,89$\pm$  0,03 &  2,27 $\pm$    0,02  & 0,92 / 0,88 / 0,89 
\\ \cline{2-2}  \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  

\hline

\multirow{64} 
& 0,25 &  0,95 $\pm$  0,04 & 0,89 $\pm$  0,02 &  2,26 $\pm$   0,02 & 0,91 / 0,91 
/0,89 \\ \cline{2-2}  \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  


& 1  & 0,95 $\pm$  0,04 & 0,82$\pm$  0,02 &  2,26 $\pm$    0,01  & 0,96 / 0,91 / 0,93  
\\  \cline{2-2} \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  


& 4  & 0,93 $\pm$  0,04 & 0,83 $\pm$  0,02 &  2,26 $\pm$   0,01  & 0,98 / 0,91 / 0,93 
\\ \cline{2-2}  \cline{3-3} \cline{4-4} \cline{5-5}  \cline{6-6}  



\cline{1-2}

\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{tabla alphas}
\label{ajustes}
\end{table}
```

la tabla se hace correctamente pero cuando quiero ubicarla en otro lugar del texto no se mueve. Se queda fija siempre en el mismo lugar. El problema es porque me tira ese error y no se como arreglarlo. Alguna idea?

se puede hacer esta tabla de otra manera sino ? necesito poner esos datos así como están pero ese error no me deja moverla del lugar fijo en el que esta en el texto

grcias.

saludos!

Comment: ¿puedes poner el mensaje de error completo? Debe mostrar qué secuencia de control fue la que no reconoció.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que esta tabla se convirtió automáticamente a LaTeX por otro programa.

Solo era necesario:

- prestar atención a la sintaxis del paquete [`multirow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow),
- poner toda la notación matemática dentro de `$ ... $`.

Pero también arreglé las líneas horizontales, ya que muchas eran redundantes.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$N$ & $\tau$ & $\alpha_E \pm\Delta\alpha_E$ & $\alpha_P \pm\Delta\alpha_P$ & $\alpha_D \pm\Delta\alpha_D$ & $R^2_E$ / $R^2_P$ / $R^2_D$\\
\hline
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{24}
 & 0,25 & 0,99$\pm$ 0,07 & 0,91 $\pm$ 0,03 & 2,72 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,67/ 0,54 /0,91\\
\cline{2-6}
 & 1 & 0,97 $\pm$ 0,07 & 0,92 $\pm$ 0,03 & 2,71 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,76 / 0,54 / 0,95\\
\cline{2-6}
 & 4 & 0,96 $\pm$ 0,07 & 0,91$\pm$ 0,03 & 2,71 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,88 / 0,82 / 0,89\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{32}
 & 0,25 & 0,96 $\pm$ 0,06 & 0,92$\pm$ 0,03 & 2,71 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,88/ 0,82 / 0,88\\
\cline{2-6}
 & 1 & 0,95 $\pm$ 0,07 & 0,94$\pm$ 0,03 & 2,27 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,85 / 0,95 / 0,89\\
\cline{2-6}
 & 4 & 0,95 $\pm$ 0,06 & 0,89$\pm$ 0,03 & 2,27 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,92 / 0,88 / 0,89\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{64}
 & 0,25 & 0,95 $\pm$ 0,04 & 0,89 $\pm$ 0,02 & 2,26 $\pm$ 0,02 & 0,91 / 0,91 /0,89\\
\cline{2-6}
 & 1 & 0,95 $\pm$ 0,04 & 0,82$\pm$ 0,02 & 2,26 $\pm$ 0,01 & 0,96 / 0,91 / 0,93\\
\cline{2-6}
 & 4 & 0,93 $\pm$ 0,04 & 0,83 $\pm$ 0,02 & 2,26 $\pm$ 0,01 & 0,98 / 0,91 / 0,93\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{tabla alphas}
\label{ajustes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Este es el resultado:

[image: screenshot of output table]

Los espacios antes y después de los `$\pm$` también deberían arreglarse, lo noté más tarde.

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google. `:)`